What does 'not at all' mean?
A: Would it be alright if I bring my little brother?
B: Not at all. But it says that you are not allowed to bring children under 8.
In this dialogue, 'Not at all' can be the asnwer of A?
The meaning of "NOT AT ALL" that I want to convey is "NO PROBLEM."

Alright = Okay, and not at all is simply emphatic definitely not. So in your context, the reply "Not at all" would mean "It's definitely not okay to bring your brother".

...but given B says But it says that you are not allowed to bring children under 8, obviously what he means is [if it was up to me] that would be okay [but it's not my decision].

Please explain the source of the dialog.

"not at all"  is in response to a negative-spin question:

Would it bother you if I listened to an experimental jazz album?"
-- Not at all.

or

Would it be a problem if I brought my little brother to the meeting?  He will be quiet.
-- Not at all.

The meaning is "not in any way a problem" or "it would not bother me even in the smallest way".  It would be OK.
If the question has no negative spin:

May I bring my little brother to the meeting?

If you wish to say, in response to that question, that bringing the little brother to the meeting is OK, you would say

Yes. That's fine.

or

Yes, you can.

or

Of course. You can bring him with you.

"Not at all" isn't appropriate, as it reverses a negative spin to yield "OK".
Mathematically:  (-1) * -1 = 1.
